# Powershell XML get attribute value with specific value from another attribute

Tags: xml, powershell, attributes

HI i'm new to Powershell and i'm trying to read an xml file with some conditions, here is the file

```
<file>
     <userlist>
         <user name="Martin" log="mr.martin@mail.com"></user>
         <user name="Tec" log="mr.tec@mail.com"></user>
         <user name="Obama" log="mr.obama@mail.com"></user>
     </userlist>
</file>
```

What i want to do is to get in a variable my name from a specific log. For exemple get name if log = mr.martin@mail.com
what i tried was this

```
$PathXML="Path\conf.xml"
 $xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
 $xml.Load($PathXML)
$name = $xml.file.userlist.user | Select-Object -Property name | where log -eq "mr.martin@mail.com"
```

The problem is that it returns me my log instead of my name.
Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT it doesn't return me my log
but this @{name=Martin}

EDIT V2

after more research i found that my result was an Hashtable so all i have to do get the name is :

```
$var = $name.name
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use XPath. This one get's the `name` attribute directly:

```
$name = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//user[@log = "mr.martin@mail.com"]/@name')
Write-Host $name
```

This one gets the matching `<user>` element:

```
$name = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//user[@log = "mr.martin@mail.com"]')
Write-Host $user.name
```

Your approach would work better without the `Select`:

```
$user = $xml.file.userlist.user | where log -eq "mr.martin@mail.com"
Write-Host $user.name
```

With simple queries like this, using PowerShell's tools will be roughly on par with XPath, but when things a little get more complex, XPath will quickly be in the lead. That's why I usually use XPath from the start. Also, XPath will be faster than a PowerShell pipeline, which could become relevant with larger XML files.